# Strongly connected component finding based on the guava graph library with Kosaraju

Tags: java, graph, guava

I have been writing a small compiler generator for which I need to solve the strongly connected component problem. As the Guava library contains, to my knowledge, no implementation for that problem, I have decided to write my own based on Kosaraju's algorithm.

For this, I have created a `GraphUtils` class and a `GraphTraverser<T>` to iterate over the graph.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.graph.ElementOrder;
import com.google.common.graph.Graph;
import com.google.common.graph.GraphBuilder;
import com.google.common.graph.Graphs;
import com.google.common.graph.MutableGraph;

public class GraphUtils {
    private GraphUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Guarantees: the graph will be directed and forest-like without self loops.
     * 
     * @param graph
     * @return the SCC graph. each node contains all the nodes in the CC of the original graph
     */
    public static <T> Graph<Set<T>> findStronglyConnectedComponents(Graph<T> graph) {
        if (graph.nodes().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find components in an empty graph");
        }
        final MutableGraph<Set<T>> result = GraphBuilder.directed().allowsSelfLoops(false)
                .nodeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion()).build();
        // Kosaraju's algorithm

        final Map<T, Set<T>> ccStore = new HashMap<>(graph.nodes().size());
        // Step 1
        final ImmutableList<T> topologicalOrder = GraphUtils.traverse(graph).postOrderTraversal(graph.nodes()).toList()
                .reverse();
        // Step 2
        final Graph<T> transposeGraph = Graphs.transpose(graph);
        // Step 3
        for (T node : topologicalOrder) {
            if (ccStore.keySet().contains(node)) {
                continue;
            }
            final Set<T> connectedComponent = new HashSet<>();
            final Set<T> hitExistingNodes = new HashSet<>();

            GraphUtils.traverse(transposeGraph)
                    .postOrderTraversal(Collections.singleton(node), ccStore.keySet(), hitExistingNodes::add)
                    .forEach(connectedComponent::add);

            result.addNode(connectedComponent);
            hitExistingNodes.forEach(n -> {
                // We encounterd a connection between connected components
                Set<T> existingCC = ccStore.get(n);
                result.putEdge(existingCC, connectedComponent);
            });
            connectedComponent.forEach(n -> {
                ccStore.put(n, connectedComponent);
            });
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static <T> GraphTraverser<T> traverse(Graph<T> graph) {
        return new GraphTraverser<>(graph);
    }
}
```

`GraphTraverser<T>`

```
import com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator;
import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;
import com.google.common.graph.Graph;

public class GraphTraverser<T> {
    private static final class PostOrderNode<T> {
        public final T root;
        public final Iterator<T> childIterator;

        public PostOrderNode(T root, Iterator<T> childIterator) {
            this.root = Objects.requireNonNull(root);
            this.childIterator = Objects.requireNonNull(childIterator);
        }
    }

    private final class PostOrderIterator extends AbstractIterator<T> {
        private final ArrayDeque<PostOrderNode<T>> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        private final Iterator<T> rootNodes;
        private final Set<T> visitedSet;
        private final Set<T> ignoredSet;
        private final Consumer<T> ignoreNodeEncountered;

        public PostOrderIterator(Collection<T> roots, Set<T> ignoredNodes, Consumer<T> ignoreNodeMet) {
            this.rootNodes = roots.iterator();
            this.visitedSet = new HashSet<>(graph.nodes().size());
            this.ignoredSet = ignoredNodes;
            this.ignoreNodeEncountered = ignoreNodeMet;
        }

        @Override
        protected T computeNext() {
            while (stack.isEmpty() && rootNodes.hasNext()) {
                pushNodeIfUnvisited(rootNodes.next());
            }
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                PostOrderNode<T> top = stack.getLast();
                if (top.childIterator.hasNext()) {
                    T child = top.childIterator.next();
                    pushNodeIfUnvisited(child);
                } else {
                    stack.removeLast();
                    return top.root;
                }
            }
            return endOfData();
        }

        private void pushNodeIfUnvisited(T t) {
            if (ignoredSet.contains(t)) {
                if (ignoreNodeEncountered != null) {
                    ignoreNodeEncountered.accept(t);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (!visitedSet.add(t)) {
                return;
            }
            stack.addLast(expand(t));
        }

        private PostOrderNode<T> expand(T t) {
            return new PostOrderNode<T>(t, graph.successors(t).iterator());
        }
    }

    private final Graph<T> graph;

    public GraphTraverser(Graph<T> graph) {
        this.graph = Objects.requireNonNull(graph);
    }

    public FluentIterable<T> postOrderTraversal() {
        return postOrderTraversal(graph.nodes());
    }

    public FluentIterable<T> postOrderTraversal(Collection<T> rootNodes) {
        return postOrderTraversal(rootNodes, Collections.emptySet(), null);
    }

    /**
     * Does post order traversal of the (directed) graph. When a node in ignoredNodes is encountered, ignoreNodeMet is
     * called
     * 
     * @param rootNodes
     *            the nodes to start traversal at
     * @param ignoredNodes
     *            nodes that will be ignored, i.e. not recursively traversed
     * @param ignoredNodeMet
     *            might be null for no callback
     * @return
     */
    public FluentIterable<T> postOrderTraversal(Collection<T> rootNodes, Set<T> ignoredNodes,
            Consumer<T> ignoredNodeMet) {
        return new FluentIterable<T>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return new PostOrderIterator(rootNodes, ignoredNodes, ignoredNodeMet);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's an example usage, with current, correct output:

```
MutableGraph<Integer> originalGraph = GraphBuilder.directed().expectedNodeCount(10).build();
originalGraph.putEdge(1, 0);
originalGraph.putEdge(2, 1);
originalGraph.putEdge(0, 2);
originalGraph.putEdge(0, 3);
originalGraph.putEdge(5, 3);
originalGraph.putEdge(3, 4);

System.out.println(originalGraph);
// isDirected: true, allowsSelfLoops: false, nodes: [1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4], edges: [<1 -> 0>, <0 -> 2>, <0 -> 3>, <2 -> 1>, <3 -> 4>, <5 -> 3>]
Graph<Set<Integer>> sccGraph = GraphUtils.findStronglyConnectedComponents(originalGraph);
System.out.println(sccGraph);
// isDirected: true, allowsSelfLoops: false, nodes: [[5], [0, 1, 2], [3], [4]], edges: [<[5] -> [3]>, <[0, 1, 2] -> [3]>, <[3] -> [4]>]
```

I'm mostly interested in the design of `GraphTraverser<T>` and the efficiency of the algorithm and the returned result. If you find any bugs, please point them out. Any comments on code style and readability are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first experiments/test show that this does exactly what it says on the tin: it finds strongly connected (groups of) nodes, or -- in my non-expert parlance -- where the cycles are in a directed graph.

Cannot say much about performance, as the use case I am dealing with involves analysing small-ish graphs (a few dozen nodes at most). Just wondering why your solution doesn't use the Traverser that guava/google graph ships.

Also, noticed that you explicitly forbid self-loops, yet when I analyse a Graph with a self-loop in it, it all works wonderfully well (the self-loop is identified as a cycle Set of one).

In short, thanks very much for helping me out of a pickle

Comment: The method guarantees, i.e. ensures no self-loops of the returned value, it's not a restriction on the argument.